# How to import module from another project

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my folder: PycharmProjects:
project1 -database/mainconfig.py
project2-main_run.py

From project2 main_run.py I need to reference a module from mainconfig.py in project1.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First make sure both the project1 and project2 files are in same folder. Then u can add this import statement in project2:

```
from mainconfig import *
```